# How to play a audio file through http response in django(python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-views

I want to make request to url  and django view should read the file and send the http response back to play the same file in browser.I got the following code but it does't play anything please anyone help me..
Right now i hard coded  the file name in the code.

```
url: http://localhost/playfile/audiofile_name
def playAudioFile(request): 
    try:
        fname="C:\\test\\audio\\t.mp3"    
        wrapper = FileWrapper(file(fname))
        print content_type
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type="audio/mpeg")
        print response
        response['Content-Length'] =os.path.getsize(fname )
        return response
    except:
        return HttpResponse()
```

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer.....

```
 def playAudioFile(request):
    fname="C:\\test\\audio\\audio.mp3"
    f = open(fname,"rb") 
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.write(f.read())
    response['Content-Type'] ='audio/mp3'
    response['Content-Length'] =os.path.getsize(fname )
    return response
```

Comment: Tried the same but a loader keeps on rotating and nothing happens. Audio never plays

Comment: This is working fine how can i automatically dowload that file

Answer (score -6):

well if you have the file you can do this

```
s = Sound() 
s.read('sound.wav') 
s.play()
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's a `Sound` class in django and it would behave as the question author expects?

Comment: Totally out of the context answer. I dont think there's anything like that in django or even python