# Play an audio file from server django

Tags: ajax, django

I am planning to make a dropbox like app using django.I could achieve uploading file into server and showing it on the browser.I want users to be able to download or view it.I am trying it for an audio file initially.Ive attached my views.py and index.html file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from polls.models import Files
from os import walk
from os.path import isfile, join
def index(request):
        return render(request,"index.html", {})

def upload(request):
    for x in request.FILES.getlist("files"):
        def process(f):
            with open(r'C:\Users\rdoshi\storage\%s ' %f.name , 'wb+') as destination:
                b = Files(file_name= f.name)
                b.save()
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
        process(x)
    q = Files.objects.all()
    return render(request,  "index.html", {'q' : q})
def play_file(request) : 
    file=Files.objects.get(id=37)
    fsock = open(r'C:\Users\rdoshi\storage\%s' %file.file_name, 'r')
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='audio/mpeg')
    return response
```

Index.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //$("#playlink").click(function(e){
    //  e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/polls/play_file',
            //data: {'id': 37},
            success: function (recvd_file) {
                 //this gets called when server returns an OK response
                 console.log("success");
                var asd = '<audio id="myaudio" src="recvd_file.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>';
                document.write(asd);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
<table id='filetable' border = '1'>
{% for i in q  %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{i.id}}</td>
   <td>
   {{i.file_name}}
   <button type="button" id='playlink' value = 'Download'>Download</button>
   </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
<form method = "post" action="../upload/" enctype ="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
         <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
         <input type = "submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

So trying to play the file gives me this error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 159: character maps to 
I am assuming problem is with fsock in views.py...could someone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file in read mode, but the file is a binary file. ( Notice that you also write the file in `wb+` mode )

change

```
fsock = open(r'C:\Users\rdoshi\storage\%s' %file.file_name, 'r')
```

to

```
fsock = open(r'C:\Users\rdoshi\storage\%s' %file.file_name, 'rb')
```

Also, have a look at [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457408/how-to-play-a-audio-file-through-http-response-in-djangopython) to set `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`

Comment: Yes that did it....Can you also tell what to add in src of success method ajax of index.html?

Comment: Well, you'll have to put the base64 audio binary data into the src - take a look at [html5 media and data uri # Audio Section](https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri) and also [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467922/setting-html5-media-source-using-ajax)